# Trouble with pointers in C code

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Language: C

Global variables

```
char array[1001]={0};
char result[1001]={0};

//main()

//lasta - index of last element in array[], lastr - index for result[]
//larr - pointer to larger array (array[] or result[])
//bint - pointer to bigger of lasta or lastr, sint - smaller

int i = 0, lasta = 0, lastr = 0, overflow = 0;
char *larr, *sarr;
int *bint, *sint;
scanf("%s", array); //init arrays - ok
scanf("%s", result);

//some routines, include output of arrays, whitch don't modify global arrays
//...

// next 3 lines is just debug output. No troubles, all correct
printf("\narray:  %s\n", array);
printf("\nresult: %s\n", result);
printf("\nlasta = %d, lastr = %d, arr[lasta]=%d, res[lastr]=%d\n", lasta, lastr, array[lasta], array[lastr]);

if (lasta > lastr)
{
    larr = array;
    sarr = result;
    bint = &lasta;
    sint = &lastr;
}
else
{
    larr = result;
    sarr = array;
    bint = &lastr;
    sint = &lasta;
}
putc('5', stdout); // no ouput: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If i modify if-else blocks in such way:

```
    larr = array;
    putc('5', stdout);
    sarr = result;
    putc('5', stdout);
    bint = &lasta;
    putc('5', stdout);
    sint = &lastr;
    putc('5', stdout);
```

there is no "Segmentation fault." more

What's wrong with pointers?

p.s. System: FreeBSD 9.1, compilers: gcc 4.6, gcc 4.9, clang

Trouble found: my stupid.
incorrect work with pointers bint/sint (I used *bint-- instead of *bint -= 1) in end of main().
putc(..) didn't print anything because there was no calls of fflush(stdout).

Comment: Does your code compiles?

Comment: Hey, you commented `main` as well.

Comment: SSCCE? Sounds like you might be writing to bad memory elsewhere.

Comment: The problem lies either in what you marked as `//some routines` or in whatever follows that `if-else`. One way or other, it seems that you're experiencing an undefined behavior.

Comment: yes. There are only 3 warnings with -Wall key - unused variables

Comment: here is "routines":  
     while(array[i]||result[i])
     {
         if(array[i])
             lasta = i;
         if(result[i])
             lastr = i;
         i++;
     }

Comment: Your loop will be finding the wrong length for array/result (making whichever is shorter become too big). This could be the starting point of your problems, but as I said before, your issue is most likely that you are setting memory which doesn't belong to you somewhere (e.g overflowing an array boundary)

Comment: You should really think about using better identifiers. It's really hard to read your code. At least, you should avoid abbreviations like `larr`, `sarr`, `bint`, and `sint`. The time you save by typing such abbreviations is disproportionally smaller than the time you will waste when you try to understand your own code a month or a year later. Good identifiers that readily reveal the _purpose_ of a variable are an investment with an awesome interest rate!

Comment: It's too small (80 lines) program for worry about identifiers. And I write this program only to study c. I've done task, get some skill and won't back to this code.

Answer (score 0):

array[lasta] and array[lastr] are of type char, you printf them with %d - that's likely to mess with memory since the sizes are not matched. Since this is UB, you might get any error, I guess in this case is propagates only when trying to print something else

Comment: I've deleted that output at all. (i've deleted all kind of output except putc(...).

$ ./a.out
10
101010100101

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Printf is variadic therefore all int-like numbers are promoted to int anyway. This won't be causing the issue.